# Как сделать вывод случайных картинок без повторений в Telegram бота на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот код который выводит случайные картинки, но они повторяются. Что нужно исправить?

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.chat.id;

  if (msg.text === 'Закрыть') {
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Закрываю клавиатуру', {
      reply_markup: {
        remove_keyboard: true,
      },
    });
  } else if (msg.text === 'cccc') {
    var random_img = ['c1.jpg', 'c2.jpg', 'c3.jpg'];

    var foto = random_img[Math.floor(Math.random() * random_img.length)];

    bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, foto);
  } else if (msg.text === 'dddd') {
    var random_img = ['d1.jpg', 'd2.jpg', 'd3.jpg'];

    var foto = random_img[Math.floor(Math.random() * random_img.length)];

    bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, foto);
  } else {
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Клавиатура', {
      reply_markup: {
        keyboard: [
          ['Закрыть'],
          ['cccc', 'dddd']
        ],
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея простая удаляйте уже отправленные картинки из массива. Только вот есть небольшие ньюансы, этот метод для единичного случая. Вам нужно будет хранить массивы отправленных фото в разрезе чатов если хотите чтобы фото повторялись по чатам но в одном чате нет

```js
const img_c = ['c1.jpg','c2.jpg','c3.jpg'];
const img_d = ['d1.jpg','d2.jpg','d3.jpg'];

bot.on('message', msg => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id

    if (msg.text === 'Закрыть') {

        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Закрываю клавиатуру', {
            reply_markup:{
                remove_keyboard: true
            }
        })

    } else if (msg.text === 'cccc') { 

      let foto = img_c[(Math.floor(Math.random() * img_c.length))];

      let index = img_c.indexOf(foto);

      if (index > -1) {
        img_c.splice(index, 1);
        bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, foto); 
      }  

    } else if (msg.text === 'dddd') { 

          let foto = img_d[(Math.floor(Math.random() * img_d.length))];

          let index = img_d.indexOf(foto);

          if (index > -1) {
            img_d.splice(index, 1);
            bot.sendPhoto(msg.from.id, foto);   
          }  
          
          
   } else {
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Клавиатура', {
        reply_markup: {
            keyboard: 
            [ 
            ['Закрыть'],
            ['cccc','dddd'] 
            ]
        }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: А чтобы при выходе и входе в чат информация о массиве сбрасывалась, так не получится?

Comment: Не вариантов много я имею ввиду что бы массив был виден для чата и он был нужный. Что спокойно удалять из него элементы во избежание повторений